# Анимированный текст в TextView

Tags: android, textview

Есть ли какие-то стандартные Android-средства, которые позволяют сделать передвижение текста, если он не вмещается в TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведите ваш `TextView` к такому типу:

```
<TextView
android:text="Ооооооооооооочень большооооооооой текст"
android:id="@+id/marquee" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
android:paddingRight="15dip" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:freezesText="true">
```

Далее в коде

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.marquee)).setSelected(true);
```

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working)